# java SocketPermission only works in eclipse not in tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat

In our application have to call external web service.We enabled java security manager to our project.
This is how we grant the permission to call the web service,

**permission java.net.SocketPermission "servername:80", "connect, resolve";**

it's work perfectly on eclipse IDE.but when we deployed it into tomcat server , no responed.
Any ideas? Please help.

Comment: Tomcat is 8080 by default, is tomcat listening on 80?

Comment: "No response" doesn't indicate a permission problem.

Comment: I fixed that problem. We have to add SocketPermission and other security permissions of the security manager in  catalina.policy file(WEB APPLICATION PERMISSIONS)as well in order to run perfectly. thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed that problem. Need to add SocketPermission and other security permissions of the security manager in catalina.policy file(WEB APPLICATION PERMISSIONS)as well in order to run perfectly.